# STANZA/ RuntimeError: Integer division of tensors using div or / is no longer supported

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, stanza

I want to use stanza for tokenizing, pos tagging and parsing some text I have, but it keeps giving me this error. I've tried changing the way a I call it but nothing happens. Any ideas?

My code(Here a iterate through a list of list of text and appli stanza to each one)

```
t = time()

data_stanza = []
for text in data:
    stz = apply_stanza(text[0])
    data_stanza.append(stz)

print('Time to run: {} mins'.format(round((time() - t) / 60, 2)))
```

This is the function I use to `apply_stanza` to each text:

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline('pt')

def apply_stanza(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    All = []
    for sent in doc.sentences:
        for word in sent.words:
            All.append((word.id,word.text,word.lemma,word.upos,word.feats,word.head,word.deprel))
    return All
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-7ac303eec8e8> in <module>
      3 data_staza = []
      4 for text in data:
----> 5     stz = apply_stanza(text[0])
      6     data_stanza.append(stz)
      7 

<ipython-input-16-364c3ac30f32> in apply_stanza(text)
      2 
      3 def apply_stanza(text):
----> 4     doc = nlp(text)
      5     All = []
      6     for sent in doc.sentences:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\pipeline\core.py in __call__(self, doc)
    174         assert any([isinstance(doc, str), isinstance(doc, list),
    175                     isinstance(doc, Document)]), 'input should be either str, list or Document'
--> 176         doc = self.process(doc)
    177         return doc
    178 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\pipeline\core.py in process(self, doc)
    168         for processor_name in PIPELINE_NAMES:
    169             if self.processors.get(processor_name):
--> 170                 doc = self.processors[processor_name].process(doc)
    171         return doc
    172 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\pipeline\mwt_processor.py in process(self, document)
     31                 preds = []
     32                 for i, b in enumerate(batch):
---> 33                     preds += self.trainer.predict(b)
     34 
     35                 if self.config.get('ensemble_dict', False):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\models\mwt\trainer.py in predict(self, batch, unsort)
     77         self.model.eval()
     78         batch_size = src.size(0)
---> 79         preds, _ = self.model.predict(src, src_mask, self.args['beam_size'])
     80         pred_seqs = [self.vocab.unmap(ids) for ids in preds] # unmap to tokens
     81         pred_seqs = utils.prune_decoded_seqs(pred_seqs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\models\common\seq2seq_model.py in predict(self, src, src_mask, pos, beam_size)
    259             done = []
    260             for b in range(batch_size):
--> 261                 is_done = beam[b].advance(log_probs.data[b])
    262                 if is_done:
    263                     done += [b]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stanza\models\common\beam.py in advance(self, wordLk, copy_indices)
     82         # bestScoresId is flattened beam x word array, so calculate which
     83         # word and beam each score came from
---> 84         prevK = bestScoresId / numWords
     85         self.prevKs.append(prevK)
     86         self.nextYs.append(bestScoresId - prevK * numWords)

RuntimeError: Integer division of tensors using div or / is no longer supported, and in a future release div will perform 
true division as in Python 3. Use true_divide or floor_divide (// in Python) instead.
```

ATT: It turns after all that it was and error with the mwt module of stanza pipeline, so I just specified not to use it.

Comment: Which python version are you using? If python 2, then upgrade to python 3

Comment: So, according to my Jupyter Notebook environment, I'm using Python 3

Comment: your code is working fine in my system

Comment: Would uninstall and install Jupyter work?

Comment: Reinstall `stanza` in python 3

Comment: I think I know what is happening, I downloaded stanza via anaconda but it does not support Python 3.8 and my cmd is not recognizing the pip install command (wich was the reason I used conda install)

Answer (score 0):

Use  `//` for division instead of `/`.

Try to edit your code as follows:

```
print('Time to run: {} mins'.format(round((time() - t) // 60, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using floor division (//) will floor the result to the largest possible integer.

Using **torch.true_divide(Dividend, Divisor)** or **numpy.true_divide(Dividend, Divisor)** in stead.

For example: 3/4 = torch.true_divide(3, 4)

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.true_divide.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html